# I am designing the initial part of a fraction calculator

Tags: java, calculator

This initial part is just supposed to take a mixed fraction like 1 1/2 and convert it to 3/2

What I have is below, the problem is that when I run it it gives me an error. said error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:18)
```

Code begins below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prompt user for fraction string
        // receive and store in variable
        // convert to improper fraction
        //print

        System.out.println("Enter a fraction:"); //prompt for string
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Receive

        String fractionAsString = input.next(); //store in variable

        int getSpace = fractionAsString.indexOf('_'); //should fine where java spaces for the initial entering of fractoin

        int getSlash = fractionAsString.indexOf('/'); //should find divisor (like in 1 1/2)

        String firstString= fractionAsString.substring(0, getSpace+1);//converting string to int

        String secondString=fractionAsString.substring(getSpace, getSlash);

        String thirdString=fractionAsString.substring(getSlash+1);

        int wholeNumber=Integer.parseInt(firstString);

        int numerator=Integer.parseInt(secondString);

        int denominator=Integer.parseInt(thirdString);

        int newResult=wholeNumber*denominator;

        int finalResult=numerator+newResult;

        System.out.println(finalResult+"/"+denominator);

        input.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `input.next()`. Since you need the whole string which the user entered you should use `nextLine()` not `next()`.

Reason:

`next()` takes space as the default delimiter.

`nextLine()` takes return as the default delimiter.

Be warned there are other problems in your code. You may want to print variables to know what is stored in them.

Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `next()` takes space as the default delimiter, Use `nextLine()` as it takes return as the default delimiter. By the way use some custom operator like underscore(_) to represent whole-number instead of using space. And split the string to get wholeNumber, numerator and denominator.